# How can I redirect from a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form which sends the request to my API and either displays the error under form, or redirects to another page. Or, at least, it's supposed to. This is my form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import '../Auth.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

function SendRegisterRequest(email, username, password){
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    var body = {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    };
    
    axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/v1/identity/register', body)
      .then(function (response) {
        navigate("/confirm");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = error.response.data.errors[0];
      });
  }

class Register extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            username: '',
            password: '',
            cpassword: '',
        };

        this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleCpasswordChange = this.handleCpasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleEmailChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
    }

    handleCpasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ cpassword: event.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.password != this.state.cpassword){
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Passwords don't match!";
        }
        else {
        SendRegisterRequest(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password);
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
                        <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="email"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
                        <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.username}
                            onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="email">
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="password"
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group size="lg" controlId="password">
                        <Form.Label>Confirm password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="password"
                            value={this.state.cpassword}
                            onChange={this.handleCpasswordChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <p id="errorMessage"></p>
                    <Button size="lg" type="submit" >
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Register
```

The `SendRegisterRequest()` is called on submitting the form. Using `navigate` was causing errors because I can't use hooks in functions. I have also tried returning the `<Navigate/>` component:

```
axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/v1/identity/register', body)
  .then(function (response) {
    return <Navigate to="/confirm"/>
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = error.response.data.errors[0];
  });
```

And after debugging, I can see that `return <Navigate to="/confirm"/>` is being hit, but nothings happens. What am I doing wrong here? Or maybe is there any other way that I can simply redirect to another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `history` which, per [react-router docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history):

> refers to the history package, which is one of only 2 major dependencies of React Router (besides React itself)

Step by step below:

1. Create a `history` instance:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

2. Pass created `history` instance to main app router

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

// in an app main render() if class component or return if functional component: 

<Router history={history}>
   <RestOfApp/>
</Router>
```

3. Import the same `history` instance in your `axios` method and call

```
history.push('/confirm')
```

More info how to use the `history` package can be found in it's [docs](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/dev/docs/getting-started.md) (v5)

Comment: By main app router you mean the Router component in App.js?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assume you've got only one Router in the application which wraps it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have a `Router` component, but `BrowserRouter`. Is this an issue or will it work?

Comment: I expermented a bit with what you suggested and it satifies my needs, to I will mark your asnwer as correct. I posted what I accomplished below.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Register Class Component into Functional Component . Create navigate in Register class component and pass navigate in SendRegisterRequest method.

```
function SendRegisterRequest(email, username, password,navigate){
    var body = {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/v1/identity/register', body)
  .then(function (response) {
    navigate("/confirm");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = error.response.data.errors[0];
  });


 }

function Register (){
const navigate=useNavigate();
...
 handleSubmit = (event) => {
        ...
        SendRegisterRequest(email, username, password,navigate);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to turn it into a functional component. As I was doing it with functional component, my app was sending the request every time a state was updated, that's why I am using the class component, and that's why the question is about class component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but it is a bit inelegant and won't satisify those who want their page to work without refreshing.

Inspired by @kmnowak I experimented a bit and finally did this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

function SendRegisterRequest(email, username, password) {
    const history = createBrowserHistory({forceRefresh:true});
    var body = {
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password
    };

    axios.post('https://localhost:5001/api/v1/identity/register', body)
        .then(function (response) {
            history.push('/posts');
            document.location.reload()
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = error.response.data.errors[0];
        });
}
```

the `history.push('/posts')` changes the URL route, but doesn't change the page content, so I use `document.location.reload()` to force reload the page.

Comment: I'd recommend creating ONE global history and import it across the app to provide one source of truth for that. Why? Imagine creating many of them. Each of them has own stack. One day you want to go back (pop something out of history1) but you use history2.pop() and you miss all information from history1.

TLDR: create 1 history globally and import it to your axios request file